# How to load an image in R

Tags: r, image

Im trying to import an image from my computer into R. Im using the `imager` package. The image is in .jpeg format and the path to the image is definitely correct. Here's the code I'm using:

```
library(imager)
fpath <- system.file("/Users/Name/Desktop/test.jpeg", package = "imager") 
im <- load.image(fpath)
```

But this throws back this error:

```
Error in wrap.url(file, load.image.internal) : File not found
```

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here as imager supports .jpeg and there isn't a lot of people talking about how to import from your own computer online... any suggestions as to how I'd fix this?

Comment: You probably just want `load.image("/Users/Name/Desktop/test.jpeg")`. Your call to `system.file` is looking for that path inside the `imager` library folder, which why it claims to not exist.